# python socket connection detection

Tags: python, at-command

I have a small program that writes AT commands over ethernet.  How do I get it to detect if a connection is established to my device or not?

I have this:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host, port))

s.send blah blah blah
```

I've read about fileno() and _closed.  But how do I use those?

Comment: I would expect that it will raise exception when there is no connection or when other side disconnects - and this doesn't need `fileno()` nor `_closed`

Comment: What do you mean?  So right now, if I run the script it'll timeout.  But I need the script do output an error message when there's no connection to my device.  How do I do this?

Comment: `timeout` also raises exception and you should use `try/except` to catch it - and then you can display message.